# Meteor mongo: Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403]

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The following snippet gives me the error:

```
Households.update({
    _id: Meteor.user().profile.myHousehold, 
    "shoppingList.name" : this.name}, 
    {"$set" : {
         "shoppingList.$.checked" : checked
    }
});
```

Wot? I *am* updating by id. As a workaround, I could of course simply replace the whole array `shoppingList`, but that would be brute force.

Comment: what's myHousehold equal to?  quite possibly it isn't set?

Comment: It's just a reference to the Household the user is in. It's the UUID of the household.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper pattern for using complex update/delete selectors with latency compensation is to use a Meteor method.

Shared code:

```js
Meteor.methods({

  setHouseholdChecked: function(shoppingListName, checked) {

    check(this.userId, String);
    check(shoppingListName, String);
    check(checked, Boolean);

    Households.update({
      _id: Meteor.user().profile.myHousehold, 
      "shoppingList.name" : shoppingListName
    }, {
      $set: {
        "shoppingList.$.checked" : checked
      }
    });

  }

});
```

Client code:

```
Meteor.call('setHouseholdChecked', this.name, checked);
```

Comment: No 3 ways binding in this case, with allow/deny on server side :/

Answer (score 2):

For a client only solution you could rely on this trick :

```
var households = Houseolds.find({
  _id: Meteor.user().profile.myHousehold,
  "shoppingList.name" : this.name
});
households.forEach(function(houseold){
  Households.update(houseold._id, {
    $set: {
      "shoppingList.$.checked" : checked
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This may yield a different result than desired, depending on if `"shoppingList.name" : this.name` is irrelevant or not.

Comment: This is something different. Here, every item in the shoppingList is set checked whereas in my original code, only the one with the right name is set checked.

Comment: You're right, edited my answer to provide an alternative client only solution if relevant.